# Some techniques to test for diagnalizibility for some random Matrix, lets say A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

And say that it is diagonalizable, How would I go about finding a matrix U such that A = U B U^-1?

Say I had an expression such as A = D P P-1. And all these quantities are matrices. Is it legal to algebraically move these quanties around like they are algebraic quanties? For instance, Can I write A D^-1 = P P^-1 ? Is that allowed?

Comment: No, but you could multiply left side by $D^{-1}$ and get $D^{-1}A=PP^{-1}$. There are restrictions when operating on matrices.

Comment: A good start is to find eigenvectors/eigenvalues. If all eigenvalues are distinct, the matrix is diagonable.

Comment: Did you mean $A=PDP^{-1}$? Otherwise $A=DPP^{-1}$ implies $A=D$.

Comment: @Mateusz How is that any different from the regular way?

Comment: A random matrix is diagonalisable with the probability one.

Comment: Also, in numerical computing (unless a very very very special structure like being nilpotent etc is considered), any matrix is diagonalisable with probability one due to rounding errors.

Comment: @user149635: In most cases - it just won't work (the output will be different, as in multiplying two matrices: in most cases $AB$ is different from $BA$, furthermore, it is possible that multiplication $AB$ will work and it is impossible to multiply $BA$). Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29#Basic_operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the characteristic equation of the matrix to compute its eigenvalues.  If these eigenvalues are distinct (this is equivalent to its eigenspaces being orthogonal and it can be shown that the eigenvectors that correspond to these eigenvalues are linearly independent), then the matrix is diagonalizable (note that the converse of this statement is false in general) in the following way: Let $A$ be the matrix that we are trying to diagonalize. If $\vec{\alpha_{i}}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ for $i=1,...n$ such that $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ for $i \neq j$, then we have the following diagonalization $$A=PDP^{-1}$$
for $$P=\begin{pmatrix} \, & \, & \, & \, \\ \vdots & \vdots & \, & \vdots \\ \vec{\alpha_1} & \vec{\alpha_2} & \cdots & \vec{\alpha_n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \, & \vdots \\ \, & \, & \, & \, \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$D=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & \, & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & 0 & \ddots & & \vdots\\ \, & \vdots &  & & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}\,\,,$$
where $D$ is clearly diagonal and $P$ is a change-of-basis matrix. In regards to your question about matrix manipulation, you cannot manipulate matrices like algebraic quantities, in general. By the definition of matrix multiplication, it is different to multiply a matrix on the right than it is to multiply on the left.  However, many of the algebraic axioms that you are familiar with are preserved to at least some degree in the space of matrices.