# Find a matrix $P$ that orthogonally diagonalizes $A$ and determine $P^{-1}AP$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm completely lost on how to finish this problem. The problem from the book is

> Find a matrix $P$ that orthogonally diagonalizes $A$ and determine $P^{-1}AP$

and my matrix is the $2 \times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 2\sqrt{3} \\ 2\sqrt{3} & 7 \end{pmatrix}$$

So far I've found the characteristic equation to be $x^2-13x+30 = 0$ and have factored it to be $(x-10)(x-3)=0$ and then found the eigenvalues of $\lambda=3, 10$. My diagonal matrix then is $$D=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 10 \end{pmatrix}.$$

From this I'm supposed to find $P$ and $P^{-1}$, my values for $P$ have been wrong this whole time and I end up with 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 
2\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & 1 \\
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

The book says 
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{7}}        & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}} \\ 
 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{7}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{7}} 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I tried using the formula $\frac{\vec{v_1}}{||\vec{v_1}||}$ that looked relevant to this from the book, but I didn't end up with what the book had.

I really appreciate any help!

-Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Find the eigenvectors that correspond to $\lambda=3,10$ and then normalize them by dividing by their norm - this is necessary to produce an *orthogonal* matrix, which has *orthonormal* columns (column vectors that form an orthogonal set and are unit vectors). Refer to my answer on the following post for the form of $P$: [Some techniques to test for diagnalizibility for some random Matrix, lets say A?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793260/some-techniques-to-test-for-diagnalizibility-for-some-random-matrix-lets-say-a/793337#793337)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried normalizing them, but I end up with {{2(sqrt(3))/3(sqrt(5)), 1/3(sqrt(5))}, {(sqrt(3)/4(sqrt(19/16)), (1/4(sqrt(19/16))}}. Unfortunately, the theorems are hard for me to relate to solving these (I'm not very good at this course -_-). Do I have to normalize the column vectors from my original matrix or is it possible that I row reduced incorrectly? (I've started over about 10 times and keep ending up with the same values, but maybe I missed something?)

Comment: You might not have the correct eigenvectors...try solving the equation $$A\vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v} \iff (A - \lambda I)\vec{v} = \vec{0}$$ with each eigenvalue for $\vec{v}$. @FrankA.

Comment: @FrankA. The eigenvectors end up being $\vec{v_1}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},1\right)$, which corresponds to $\lambda_1 = 10$, and $\vec{v_2}=\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},1\right)$, corresponding to $\lambda_2 = 3$...so you can check your answers.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your response! I'm not sure what I'm doing, but for lambda = 3 I end up getting -3 -2(sqrt(3)) on the top and 0 0 on the bottom. Then I take -3x-2(sqrt(3))y = 0 and after solving for x I get x = (-2(sqrt(3))/3)y. I'm not sure where I went wrong, but just wanted to run that by you. I do get the same value for lambda = 10 though.

Comment: If you're saying you obtain $$\begin{pmatrix} -3 & -2\sqrt{3} \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ upon row-reduction, then this is the same as saying that any eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $3$ is a scalar multiple of $\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}},1\right)$. Note that $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$. @FrankA.

Comment: It follows that, with the form of the diagonal matrix $D$ you have mentioned in your question, that $$P = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ such that $$A = PDP^{-1}\,\,.$$

Comment: Ah man, I totally over looked that. I forget that rationalizing goes back like that too. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem whatsoever! @FrankA.

Answer (score 0):

"$P$ orthogonally diagonalizes $A$" means that $P$ is an *orthogonal* matrix. So, you need to normalise your eigenvectors to unit lengths.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response! I tried normalizing them, but I end up with {{2(sqrt(3))/3(sqrt(5)), 1/3(sqrt(5))}, {(sqrt(3)/4(sqrt(19/16)), (1/4(sqrt(19/16))}}. To make them unit vectors they have to = 1, but I'm not sure how to normalize them. I tried looking up examples and haven't found any that make sense to me. Am I supposed to normalize the vectors after I put them into P?

Comment: @FrankA. You calculated the eigenvectors wrongly. E.g. $A-3I$ is an entrywise positive matrix. So, in order that $(A-3I)v=0$, the eigenvector $v$ must contain one positive entry and one negative entry. Yet, all entries of your eigenvector for $\lambda=3$ are positive. The eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=10$ is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 2\sqrt{3} \\ 2\sqrt{3} & 7 \end{bmatrix}$$
and you want an orthogonal $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ is diagonal. So, let us denote
$$P = \begin{bmatrix} c & s \\ -s & c \end{bmatrix},$$
where $c^2 + s^2 = 1$ (in other words, $c$ and $s$ are cosine and sine of some angle). Notice that $P^{-1} = P^T$.

Now,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ & 3 \end{bmatrix} &= P^T A P = \begin{bmatrix} c & -s \\ s & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 2\sqrt{3} \\ 2\sqrt{3} & 7 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c & s \\ -s & c \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
6 c^2-4 \sqrt{3} c s+7 s^2 & 2 \sqrt{3} c^2-c s-2 \sqrt{3} s^2 \\
2 \sqrt{3} c^2-c s-2 \sqrt{3} s^2 & 7 c^2+4 \sqrt{3} c s+6 s^2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

From the top right element, we see that
$$2 \sqrt{3} c^2 - cs - 2\sqrt{3}s^2 = 0.$$
It is easy to see that $c,s \ne 0$, so we can divide by $c^2$ and use that $t = s/c$ is tangent of the same angle of which $c$ and $s$ are cosine and sine:
$$2 \sqrt{3} - t - 2\sqrt{3}t^2 = 0.$$
Solving the quadratic equation, we see that
$$t_1 = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \quad t_2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
Pick any of these two, get $c$ and $s$, and you'll get $P$ and the eigenvalues.

Generally, it is wise to get $c,s$ from $t$ directly, without the arc-functions, but it shouldn't matter in this case.